# Using Scanner as a parameter of a method

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to use a scanner as a method. This is what I have (I've used `int` in the meantime because I have not been able to figure out how to use Scanner as a parameter)

```
public class LoopPatterns {

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2){
        int sum = number1 + number2;    
        return sum; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(sum(3, 4));
    }
}
```

So this is what I have so far. However, the main point is that I need to get the sum of an unspecified amount of digits. I need to use a scanner but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it as a parameter of my method. Anyway, I hope that was concise enough. Thanks!

Comment: A parameter is a parameter whatever its type is!? So you probably want `public static int sum(Scanner theScanner)`

Comment: @Elchapo I have a question. You will ask one time for user input or multiple times?

Comment: why do you want to pass the Scanner to sum? Make a loop in main, that scans the nextInt(), and someway knows when to stop (either by asking how many numbers will you type or when you type some specified character) and in the loop do: summed += sum(summed, scanner.nextInt())

Answer (score 0):

Just set the method so it accepts a reference of the scanner instead of pre-written ints.

```
public static int sum(Scanner myScanner){
    int sum = 0;
    String line;
    while((line = myScanner.nextLine()) != "")
        sum += Integer.parseInt(line);

    return sum;    
}
```

This method will accept a scanner as a parameter and then keep inputting numbers into the sum until the user inputs a blank character.