# Can I use Scanner as method parameter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am taking a course on my own pace, the course was held last year and I can't find any materials on Git from people who did it already in order to compare, nor can I ask someone, so I would like to ask if you have an idea what they might mean. So I need to create different classes, one of which is Address and another is House. Now, both have the following method:

```
public static Address read(Scanner sc)
public static House read(Scanner sc)
```

The condition for the Address method is: 
**Pre**: The next line retrieved by sc contains a textual representation of an Address.
**Post**: Transforms the textual representation of the Address into an
Address object.

I have the following simple implementation:

```
public static Address read(Scanner input) throws IOException {      
    String street = input.next();
    int number = input.nextInt();
    String zip = input.next();
    String city = input.next();

    Address address = new Address(street,number,zip,city);
    return address;
}
```

For the same method in House, condition and tip:
**Pre**: The next lines retrieved by sc contains a textual representation
of a House.
**Post**: Transforms the textual representation of the House into a House
object.
**Hint**: Make use of the read method in Address.

I am not sure how to implement this and I am sure it's something easy. But somehow I need to be able to receive the whole Address object via Scanner? And then parse it together with other textual input into a House object.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I saw [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108236/using-scanner-as-a-parameter-of-a-method) thread, but it's not what I am asking for.

> Self reference: THIS IS MAGIC (use ">!")

Comment: use nextLine and parse objects inside, this is not how to implement it, you must create a parser.

Comment: call the `read` method in `Address` from `read` in `House`.

Comment: great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static House read(Scanner sc) throws IOException {
    sc.next(); //load house informations, i don't know how your file looks like

    Scanner addressSc = new Scanner(new File(/* address file path */));
    Address address = Address.read(addressSc);

    House house = new House(address, /* other parameters */);
}
```

Something like this could do the job. However I don't know how is your `House` class implemented and how your files are organized or where do you want to create `House` instance.

Comment: hmm thanks! I will give this a shot :) I knew it's not complicate, but just got confused. Thanks :)